# For which values of $d\in\mathbb{Z}$, the element 2 is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For which values of $d\in\mathbb{Z}$, the element 2 is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$? I used a theorem that says: if $p\in\mathbb{N}$ is a prime then $p$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ iff $\exists\sqrt{d}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. But this give me that for all numbers $d$, 2 is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ which is false.

Comment: If $d$ is not an integer square then $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]/(2)\cong \Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2-d)$. So $(2)$ is a prime ideal iff the latter is an integral domain iff $x^2-d\bmod 2$ is irreducible  which is never the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $d$ is not a square, because if $d$ is a square we just have $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{d}]=\Bbb Z$.

If $d$ is even, then $2$ divides $d=\sqrt{d}^2$, but $2$ does not divide $\sqrt{d}$.

If $d$ is odd, then $2$ divides $d-1=(\sqrt{d}+1)(\sqrt{d}-1)$, but $2$ does not divide $\sqrt{d}\pm 1$.

So it is indeed true that $2$ is not prime in any $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$ if $d$ is not a square.

Comment: But who is $k$?

Comment: @MathLearner sorry, I meant $d$

Comment: But for negative values of d?

Comment: $d<0$ doesn't change anything, a negative number can also be odd or even. and $\sqrt{d}$ is always defined (as a complex number)